# Is there a way to autoincrement VS2013 Installer Project version numbers

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, teamcity

We currently have several VS2013 Setup/Installer Projects configured, and need to move to an automated deployment process.

One of the things that is therefore required is an autoincrementing version number of the installer (msi).

Is there a way to do this in VS2013?  We use TeamCity for builds and deployment, and git for source control.

I gather there are other packages (Wix for example) that already support this, but if we could stick with VS2013 that would be the best for us atm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the vs extension - Auto Version Incrementer:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e30465a4-dab9-44ca-815b-b390ceeef6ab

**Update**: the requested can be achieved by the following article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22256/NewSetupVersion-for-MSI-Projects

and the described script in it:

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''  Increment the version number of an MSI setup project
''  and update relevant GUIDs
''  
''  Hans-Jürgen Schmidt / 19.12.2007  
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
set a = wscript.arguments
if a.count = 0 then wscript.quit 1

'read and backup project file
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(a(0))
s = f.ReadAll
f.Close
fbak = a(0) & ".bak"
if fso.fileexists(fbak) then fso.deletefile fbak
fso.movefile a(0), fbak

'find, increment and replace version number
set re = new regexp
re.global = true
re.pattern = "(""ProductVersion"" = ""8:)(\d+(\.\d+)+)"""
set m = re.execute(s)
v = m(0).submatches(1)
v1 = split(v, ".")
v1(ubound(v1)) = v1(ubound(v1)) + 1
vnew = join(v1, ".")
'msgbox v & " --> " & vnew
s = re.replace(s, "$1" & vnew & """")

'replace ProductCode
re.pattern = "(""ProductCode"" = ""8:)(\{.+\})"""
guid = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").Guid
guid = left(guid, len(guid) - 2)
s = re.replace(s, "$1" & guid & """")

'replace PackageCode
re.pattern = "(""PackageCode"" = ""8:)(\{.+\})"""
guid = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").Guid
guid = left(guid, len(guid) - 2)
s = re.replace(s, "$1" & guid & """")

'write project file
fnew = a(0)
set f = fso.CreateTextfile(fnew, true)
f.write(s)
f.close
```

Comment: This seems to only support incrementing AssemblyInfo.  I need something that autoincrements the version number in a Setup project.

Comment: So what about this vs2013 extension :  https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d

if you find it useful I'll update my answer.

Comment: That allow me to create setup project in VS2013 (which I already use).  I need something that can be driven by command line to either set the version number, or just update the version number.

Comment: sorry for not getting it.... is this helpful? 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22256/NewSetupVersion-for-MSI-Projects

Comment: I've only skimmed the article, but yes, I think that's exactly what I need.  Thanks.

Comment: I'll update my answer. please mark it as solved so other will benefit.